# Show website before login

Tags: windows-7, login

I have recently been asked by some people if i can help develop/deploy a solution that allows their staff to first login into their website before being able to do anything on their systems. They fear their staffs dont visit their website and will like to do this so that the first thing a staff sees before he can use his/her desktop is their website.

Please can any body give me any pointers?

Comment: This question does appear to be a staffing issue more than an technical question! And an insane one at that!

Comment: If they fear their staff don't visit their website they might try making it more interesting useful and relevant.

Comment: That's one way to generate hits on a site.

Answer (score 3):

If they really decide to do this (far be it for us IT people to judge business processes, right?), one possible solution would be a captive portal, which requires authentication, usually through a web browser, in order to use any network resources.  This wouldn't prevent a user from using local resources on the computer itself, but they're likely to need network/internet access eventually I'm assuming.  The login page itself could be linked off of the site home page.

The process for doing this is too detailed and use-case specific, but researching captive portals would yield plenty of information.  There are some open source solutions for this as well.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal

Comment: This is a better solution. I have seen it in action in my college. Students as well as staff has to perform a login before they can use networking on the systems. All the pc are connected to a main server which controls all actions.

Answer (score 2):

If you are saying you want staff to see the website before they log on to Windows (see their desktop) then this is not possible (unless you boot from a disc maybe).

You could run a script which executes at log on which automatically loads the website but the user could always just close it.

Either way, how would the user get from the browser back to their desktop? Would by closing it allow the desktop to then be shown? Unless you have staff log on to the website as well for authentication to track that they visited the site, but this still doesn't mean they will have actually read the site! Even if the website loads as they log on, is the website changing every day because if not, you won't want this to occur every day (staff will get annoyed). So will this mean you run it once a month, or just at times of updates? :)

Comment: @JaredTritsch Not really - it's just explaining some of the pitfalls the OP would have to face and does offer a work around!

Comment: quote "this is not possible".  WRONG ANSWER.  I have actually achieved something very similar to this, but it would be called more of a "hack".  Its usage is almost always malicious, so I won't be posting it...

Comment: @coltonon, so, what is the purpose of your comment?